# I am trying to read in a file and then return a list of int values using the .readlines()

Tags: python

For a school assignment

> we want to convert every item in the list to be an int using the int(val) function. This will involve first reading in the file, loading all the lines, and then looping through all lines building a second list of ints (use lst). You should return the list of ints

but I don't know how to do it.

This is what I have so far.

```
def file_int_list(file):

   with open(file, 'r+') as f:

        lst = []

        lines = f.readlines() 

        for rows in lines:

            lst.append(rows)

        return lst
```

Comment: What do you get? Is it what you expect? If not, what do you have to change? How can the advice from the assignment help you for that?

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = []
lines = f.readlines() 
for rows in lines:
   lst.extend(list(map(int, rows.split(' '))))
return lst
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?